# A problem based on the Schwarz lemma that appears to require more refined results

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem: Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in unit disk $U$ s.t. $f(0) = 1$, and $f(z) \lt M$ in $U$. Prove that $|f(z) - 1| \lt M |z|$ in the disk $\{|z| \lt 1/M\}$.

I've tried many different methods including constructing functions like $g(z) = f(\frac1M z) - 1$ and $g(z) = \frac{f(z) - 1}M$ to apply Schwarz lemma. But I can only obtain a weaker inequality that $|f(z) - 1| \lt (M+1) |z|$.

Thank you for any answers or comments.

Comment: Do you mean $|f(z)|<M$?

Comment: Maybe try composing with a Möbius transformation that maps the disk of radius $M$ to itself and sends $1$ to $0$?

Comment: It is “Schwarz” and not “Schwartz” – [Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz)

Comment: I think we can only obtain $|f(z) - 1| \lt \frac{|f(z) -  M^2|}M |z|$ by this method.@TedShifrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by maximum modulus we have $M>1$.

Let $f(z)=1+\sum_{n \ge 1}a_nz^n$.

By Parseval we have that $1+\sum_{n \ge 1} |a_n|^2 < M^2$ so $\sum_{n \ge 1} |a_n|^2<M^2-1$

By Cauchy Schwarz we have $$(\sum_{n \ge 1}|a_n|M^{-n})^2 \le \sum_{n \ge 1} |a_n|^2 \sum_{n \ge 1} M^{-2n} <(M^2-1)\frac{1}{M^2(1-1/M^2)}=1$$

Hence if $|z| =1/M$ we have $|f(z)-1| \le \sum_{n \ge 1}|a_n|M^{-n} < 1=M|z|$

But $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-1}{z}$ is analytic for $|z| \le 1/M$  and satisfies $|g(z)|<M, |z|=1/M$ hence by maximum modulus $|g(z)|<M, |z| <1/M$ so $|f(z)-1| <M|z|, |z|<1/M$ and we are done!